# Excel formula - check a column for latest date entered and if not within a set number of days of current date, change colour of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a date column that needs a new entry every time a separate form is completed and archived. A new form should be entered at least once every two weeks and so there can be multiple entries down this column over a short time frame.

I need a formula that can look at this column, find the latest date entered and if that date is more than two weeks behind the current date, change one specific cell in another column to amber. If it's more than four weeks behind the current date, change that same specific cell to red - this is the 'flag' box that lets the supervisor at a glance know if the forms are lagging behind.

I don't have VBA permissions or anything like that.

Any guidance greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked out conditional formatting?  This seems ideal for that.

Answer (score 0):

> > find the latest date entered and if that date is more than two weeks behind the current date

Is the date entered bigger and bigger?
Do you only want to judge the latest date entered?

If the above answers are "Yes", please choose a range of 'flag' box, and try the conditional formulas.

I would take my sample as an example. The range of 'flag' box is from B2 to B34.

For no color filled : `=A2<MAX($A$2:$A$34)`

For red filled : `=MAX($A$2:$A$34)-TODAY()>=28`

For amber filled : `=AND(MAX($A$2:$A$34)-TODAY()>=14,MAX($A$2:$A$34)-TODAY()<28)`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey there, thank you for this!

So I've played around with it and have the following problem:

The dates are in A, first date is A9. I put in the formulas you've listed in K9.

The first date in A9 is 28/07/2021. When I drag the dates down the row, with the three formulas in place in K9, the flag box remains blank until 12/10/2021 (current date is 28/09/2021) at which point it turns amber.

It then turns red on the 26/10/2021.

So the date check is going the wrong way?

I've tried playing around with the '>' direction but can't seem to get it to make a difference.

Thoughts?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample and the result that you need? “if that date is more than two weeks behind the current date, change one specific cell in another column to amber” does mean that date entered 2 weeks is earlier than today’s date? Besides, does cells from K9 in column K will show color for all cells with date in column A or just show the color for the latest date in column A?